# Vim Open unite in current folder

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, unite.vim

I got the following hotkey mapping:

`nnoremap <leader>f Unite file -path=~/Workspace`

This works great, however, I want to make it so that path equals the current folder I'm in (which will be seperate from working directory).

Anyone know how I can make this happen? :S

Comment: Have you tried %:p:h for current folder?

Comment: I have, it seems to treat everything after `-path=` as a string.

Comment: @RobinHeggelundHansen Some things I noticed: (1) Don't you need a `:` at the beginning of `Unite`? (2) Without a `<CR>` at the end of the map, you have to manually press enter. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: @sidyll Correct, but I left them out for brevity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using:

```
:UniteWithBufferDir file
```

or

```
:UniteWithCurrentDir file
```

(depending on what you want)

Comment: I don't understand about _Unite_ at all, and gave a generic answer. But this one seems to be the exact proper solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `expand()` function to use `%:p:h` in places where a file name is not expected (these expansions are for file-name arguments, not others like what it appears to happen with your command)

```
:echo expand('%:p:h')
```

But you can't map that directly. It is a command that needs to be built "on-the-fly", so you can use `:execute` to build and execute an evaluated expression:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :exec "Unite file -path=" . expand('%:p:h')
```

Comment: ⚠️ @ RobinHeggelundHansen Please check the other answers for more appropriate solutions as well, I'll keep mine just because it is "Vim generic" in case you, or a future viewer, needs to know this technique.

Answer (score 2):

Unite allows dynamic argument by using `backtick`, as documented in the Unite help doc:

```
You don't have to use |:execute| for dynamic arguments.
You can use evaluation cmdline by ``.
Note: In the evaluation, The special characters(spaces,  "\" and ":")
are escaped automatically.
>
    :Unite -buffer-name=search%`bufnr('%')` line:forward:wrap<CR>
```

So in your case, the mapping will be:

```
:nnoremap <leader>f :Unite file -path=`expand('%:p:h')`
```

Comment: Excellent answer as well, I'm considering deleting mine since it clearly shows a non-_Unite_ proper solution

Comment: Well @sidyll, your answer is the one that made me lookup the documentation. So you do contribute to my answer :-D

Comment: Thanks...I'm keeping it and added a note to the questioner :-)

Comment: @sidyll don't remove it. It's a great answer that I can make use of outside of unite :)